# Pool overloading in benchmark

Tags: extrinsic, transaction-pool, tx-pool

I am working on `substrate` and trying to benchmark my node. I'm sending `unsigned extrinsics` to the pool and implemented the `ValidateUnsigned` trait where I add priority, longevity, provide and require tags. The benchmark launches about 100k extrinsics, using the `author_submitExtrinsic` endpoint. While sending these extrinsics, I check the status of the pool by querying the `author_pendingExtrinsics` endpoint.

After about `14k transactions` have entered the pool, the amount of extrinsics stagnates, with sometimes ~100 extra extrinsics entering. Also looking at the extrinsic data, it looks like even after 4-5 blocks, although transactions are being executed (I see extrinsics being added to blocks in the logs), it seems like no extrinsics have been removed from the pool and I start getting nonce errors (which confirmes that they have been executed but are now being reexecuted?).

What I tried so far:

- confirming that sending a lower amount of extrinsics (10k) allows them to be processed correctly and that they are removed from the pool
- replacing my implementation of the ValidateUnsigned yields the same result

Answer (score 1):

So I can't be 100% sure of the issue, my guess is that my `validate_unsigned` logic was too heavy, causing the pool to spend too much time validating and preventing it from pruning executed transactions. Reduced the workload on the `validate_unsigned` and moved most of this heavy logic to `pre_dispatch`, might not be a perfect solution, if anyone has some better idea would love to hear it !